# decoupling of network and link layer addresses

Tags: mac-address, ip-address, gateway

can you pls help me understand what the instructor is trying to convey in the following slide.

from what I understand:- network address and link address are independent in the protocol layers but when it comes to the assignment of these addresses they are in some sense dependent in a way that for each link-layer address we need to have a network-layer address.

[image]

Comment: IMO this is a poorly written example. While technically correct, it’s confusing and it’s something you’d never see in real networks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> for each link-layer address we need to have a network-layer address

It's the other way around: the network layer (IP) uses the link layer (MAC) to deliver packets inside a local subnet. For IPv4, ARP is used to translate the local destination IP to the destination MAC address. The IP packet is encapsulated by a link-layer frame (usually Ethernet) and transported across the link-layer network.

The question *which IP address belongs to MAC address xyz* doesn't usually need an answer.

You only need a network-layer address if you use a protocol that requires those. Alternatively, you could use a protocol without network-layer addressing (like NETBIOS) but that is confined to a local segment and not routable in general.